# Inserting Image to sqlite iphone

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4

Hi All I'm New to Xcode I'm trying to insert image from UITableView to database(sqlite3) in ios 5
i tried below code

```
-(void)addItemCUR
{

    if(addStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "insert into Table(C_Name, C_Image) Values(?,?)";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [C_Name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    NSData *ImageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.C_Image)];
    int returnValue = -1;
    if(self.C_Image != nil)
       returnValue =        sqlite3_bind_blob(addStmt, 3, [ImageData bytes], [ImageData length], NULL);
    else
        returnValue =         sqlite3_bind_blob(addStmt, 4, nil, -1, NULL);



    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    else
        //SQLite provides a method to get the last primary key inserted by using sqlite3_last_insert_rowid
        rowid = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

    //Reset the add statement.
    sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
}
```

I'm getting Error like

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb7c0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x158f052 0x1720d0a 0x1590ced 0x14f5f00 0x14f5ce2 0xf8b6c 0x5c65 0x3182 0x7030 0x16d71d 0x16d952 0x9f586d 0x1563966 0x1563407 0x14c67c0 0x14c5db4 0x14c5ccb 0x1478879 0x147893e 0xdda9b 0x2ac8 0x2a25)
terminate called throwing an exceptionsharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
(gdb
```

Please any one help me to get through this thanks in advance.

Comment: You've got the reason in your error message. Why don't you search for what the reason means?

Comment: The error got solved I'm not finding the way how to get image from UITableView and insert it into database, Is der any way to do it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to store the images in local document directory.Then store the image path in sqlite.Following code will help you.

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(photo);//photo - your image
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photo.png",documentsDir]; 
[imageData writeToFile:pngFilePath atomically:YES];

NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES );
NSString *docDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photo.png", docDirectory];

sqlite3 *database;
@try 
{
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Photos(PhotoPath) VALUES('%@')",filePath];
    NSString *databasePath;
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"GolfElite.sqlite"];
    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)    
    {
        NSLog(@"DB opened...");
        sqlite3_exec(database, [query UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);   
    }

}
@catch (NSException * e) 
{
    NSLog(@"Exception = %@", e);
}
@finally
{
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
NSLog(@"Photos inserted successfully..");
```

Comment: The error got solved I'm not finding the way how to get image from UITableView and insert it into database, Is der any way to do it???

Comment: I've created array of image and assiging to cell code is as below                             cell.textLabel.text =[CurArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *cellIcon = [[self IconArray] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *cellIconimage = [UIImage imageNamed:cellIcon];
    [[cell imageView] setImage:cellIconimage];

Comment: In which place you want to store it in DB whether in didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: ya i want to store it when didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called

Comment: then use this code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath to get cell reference and get the image data. UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];UIImage *image = [cell imageView].image;then pass this image to your DB save method.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I changed but image is not getting add into Database :(

Comment: Storing Image All other fields"ll get insert into DB but not Image

Comment: refer this link http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/02/sqlite-tutorial-saving-images-in.html

Comment: That example won't save image to database any how thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason to store entire image into database?

I would like to suggest you to store image in an application's Documents/Caches folder and only  location including image name will be store into your database as varchar, instead of storing the whole image into database.
So that when next time you need to use image, you just have to follow the paths those have been store for an individual image. Thus, application also doesn't has to bother to redraw images repeatedly and that will improve your application's performance too.

Below is sample code for practice..

```
- (void)saveImage:(UIImage *)image forPerson:(NSString *)fullName  
{
    // Make file name first
    NSString *filename = [fullName stringByAppendingString:@".png"]; // or .jpg

    // Get the path of the app documents directory
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Append the filename and get the full image path
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

    //  Now convert the image to PNG/JPEG and write it to the image path
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];   

    //  Here you save the savedImagePath to your DB
    ...
}
```

To get image back and display...

```
- (UIImage *)loadImage:(NSString *)filePath  
{
    return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
}
```

Comment: I don want to browse the image i want to insert image which is in the cell of tableview

Comment: From where an image can be in your tableview cell without storing it somewhere physically except you draw image directly using [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data]. And performance point of view, to store location of image is preferable instead of storing image data into database.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example which include information with image , this code is one Demo code...

```
- (void) saveAllData {

if(isDirty) {

if(updateStmt == nil) {
const char *sql = "update Coffee Set CoffeeName = ?, Price = ?, CoffeeImage = ? Where CoffeeID = ?";
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &amp;updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 1, [coffeeName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_double(updateStmt, 2, [price doubleValue]);

NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.coffeeImage);

int returnValue = -1;
if(self.coffeeImage != nil)
returnValue = sqlite3_bind_blob(updateStmt, 3, [imgData bytes], [imgData length], NULL);
else
returnValue = sqlite3_bind_blob(updateStmt, 3, nil, -1, NULL);

sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 4, coffeeID);

if(returnValue != SQLITE_OK)
NSLog(@"Not OK!!!");

if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt))
NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

sqlite3_reset(updateStmt);

isDirty = NO;
}

//Reclaim all memory here.
[coffeeName release];
coffeeName = nil;
[price release];
price = nil;

isDetailViewHydrated = NO;
}
```

Comment: I'm not finding the way how to get image from UITableView and insert it into database, Is der any way to do it???